# difference between makeBoundHelper and registerBoundHelper within ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a custom helper to format a value, the ember-cli docs seem to indicate I either need to export makeBoundHelper from within my helper file, or registerBoundHelper from within app.js whilst importing the previously created helper function.

Is my understanding of this correct? Or can you use registerBoundHelper from within a helper file and have it register correctly.

**EDIT**

related code and error info below:

https://github.com/ridget/transactions/blob/master/app/helpers/to-currency.js

Just pushed that up, using `registerBoundHelper` results in "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/ under resolving handlebars helpers seems to indicate that I can only utilise registerBoundHelper from within app.js but not sure if this is the case or im just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per docs

makeBoundHelper is

```
A (mostly) private helper function to `registerBoundHelper`. Takes the
  provided Handlebars helper function fn and returns it in wrapped
  bound helper form.

  @private
  @method makeBoundHelper
  @for Ember.Handlebars
  @param {Function} function
  @param {String} dependentKeys*
```

So basically both does same job. Difference is `registerBoundHelper` is available as public. Also parameters are different.

```
  @method registerBoundHelper
  @for Ember.Handlebars
  @param {String} name
  @param {Function} function
  @param {String} dependentKeys*
```

makeBoundHelper doesn't take name of the helper. You may need to register helper on your own by calling

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper(name, boundFn);
```

`boundFn` is `makeBoundHelper` callback

Comment: thanks for the response, had seen this in the docs, but within the ember-cli context seem to get an unexpected result, will update with error and code sample shortly.

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/071b4bb6aad44100dc74ef8e1c79562e57038e7d/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/ext.js#L355

Comment: https://github.com/ridget/transactions/blob/master/app/helpers/to-currency.js

Just pushed that up, using `registerBoundHelper` results in "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" 


http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/ under resolving handlebars helpers seems to indicate that I can only utilise registerBoundHelper from within app.js but not sure if this is the case or im just doing it wrong. Appreciate the help.

Comment: i guess its better to use `makeBoundHelper` in `ember-cli` as it only registers the helper with the filename if it is dashed...

Comment: if you want to use `registerBoundHelper` you may endup doing it in `app.js` as you mentioned